# Error from the 94th Fibonacci number in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, overflow, fibonacci

I am calculating Fibonacci numbers in C# and I am getting wrong numbers since the number 94.

This is my code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string N = Console.ReadLine();
        ulong n = ulong.Parse(N);
        ulong[] fibonacci = new ulong[n+1];
        fibonacci[0] = 0;
        if (n == 1)
        {
            fibonacci[1] = 1;
        }
        if (n>=2)
        {
            fibonacci[1] = 1;
            for (ulong i = 2; i < n+1; i++)
            {
                fibonacci[i] = (ulong)fibonacci[i-1] + (ulong)fibonacci[i-2];
            }
         }
     }

     Console.WriteLine(fibonacci[n]);
```

I am ok until the 93th number which is 12200160415121876738, but I am getting 1293530146158671551 with the 94th, the real one is 19740274219868223167.

I don't know what could be wrong with my code.

Comment: The max value of an unsigned long is `18446744073709551615`. You're hoping to store a value that's larger than that, which won't work. I suggest you look at `BigInteger`.

Comment: So, I only have to change ulong for BigInteger?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Side note: there's no need to store all fibonacci numbers in an *array*; two numbers are enough

Comment: Thanks, the solution was really easy at least.

Comment: You are right, I gonna change that.

Answer (score 7):

I think you don't need to store the number of **N** in the **ulong** type!
It can be stored as an **int** as well!
The most massive part is to store the value of the **N**th Fibonacci number.
You can calculate it more concise without considering a large array for constructing the last number!

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string N = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = int.Parse(N);
        BigInteger[] fibonacci = new BigInteger[3];
        fibonacci[0] = 0;
        fibonacci[1] = 1;
        fibonacci[2] = 1;
        
        if (n>=3)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < n+1; i++)
            {
                fibonacci[0]=fibonacci[1];
                fibonacci[1]=fibonacci[2];
                fibonacci[2]=fibonacci[1]+fibonacci[0];
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine(fibonacci[2]);
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [maximum value of `ulong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64.maxvalue?view=net-5.0) is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

You're trying to store 19,740,274,219,868,223,167, which is larger than that. By default a `ulong` won't throw an exception when it overflows, but you can force it to by adding a `checked { }` around the code:

```
checked
{
    fibonacci[i] = (ulong)fibonacci[i-1] + (ulong)fibonacci[i-2];
}
```

Then running your code, sure enough, we get:

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Fortunately, there is a type in .NET for working with really big integers. It's called [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0).

Changing your code to use it is relatively trivial:

```
string N = Console.ReadLine();
ulong n = ulong.Parse(N);
BigInteger[] fibonacci = new BigInteger[n+1];
fibonacci[0] = 0;
if (n == 1)
{
    fibonacci[1] = 1;
}
if (n>=2)
{
    fibonacci[1] = 1;
    for (ulong i = 2; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2];
    }
 }
```

Your code now works as expected and outputs:

> 19740274219868223167

Even changing the input to 900 still works:

> 54877108839480000051413673948383714443800519309123592724494953427039811201064341234954387521525390615504949092187441218246679104731442473022013980160407007017175697317900483275246652938800

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/WQF99649)

Comment: Thanks!. I come from python and all related to data types is kinda new for me.